# No package php-imap available on CentOS 7

Tags: php, centos7

I'm running a dedicated server with CentOS 7 64bit, here is the output when trying to install IMAP:

```
yum install php-imap  
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror  
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  
 * base: ftp.ciril.fr  
 * extras: ftp.ciril.fr  
 * updates: ftp.ciril.fr  
No package php-imap available.  
Error: Nothing to do
```

Also the same when disabling exclusions:

```
sudo yum install --disableexcludes=all php-imap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.ciril.fr
 * extras: ftp.ciril.fr
 * updates: ftp.ciril.fr
No package php-imap available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: I typically run `sudo yum list *imap*` to see what there is to install. This yielded 'php56-php-imap.x86_64' this time, but is helpful for all kinds of installs, to see if I need to add a repo or just get the name right.

Answer (score 6):

Just run the following commands

`yum install epel-release*`

`yum install php-imap*`

Comment: This needs explanation. And you also need quoting in those commands.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this answer. It's pretty self-explaining. You must install `EPEL` repository, then you will be able to get `php-imap` package. It's working here like a charm.

Comment: The `yum -y install epel-release` command worked perfectly for me. (CentOS 7)

Answer (score 3):

It's in the epel repo. See http://pkgs.org for a search function for such things.

Answer (score 0):

here was what I did to install PHP7.0 IMAP Extension on Centos 7.1

I downloaded setup-ius.sh from here: https://gist.github.com/SunDi3yansyah/3edc2370268c335362c896cd2d1094ad

Then, install it using command:

```
yum install php70u-imap
```

And it worked! Good luck!

Comment: This also requires switching PHP to the IUS builds, which many people will be unwilling to do.

Answer (score 0):

For Amazon Linux 2 (AL2), I've struggled to install imap extension on PHP 8.0 but I was able to this way:

```
yum update -y
yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum install -y https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum install -y php80-php-imap

cp /opt/remi/php80/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/imap.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/
/bin/echo 'extension="imap.so"' > /etc/php.d/40-imap.ini

systemctl restart php-fpm
```

The trick is to use Remi repository as they have compiled imap extension. I'm guessing that further on, the standard

Comment: This is not the proper way, see the wizard instructions https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: It looks like you need php-imap (from remi-php80, not php80-php-imap which is designed for parallel installation, a SCL)